# Preventing a window from gaining focus automatically (using Windows API)

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

I'm trying to automate a legacy windows application, and I'm facing a problem. The rude program steals focus when it has new information to show, and makes it so painful for the user to work with that computer.

Is there any possible way, maybe using Windows API, to stop the program from focus stealing?

Comment: Create a desktop and execute the program in that desktop. Then it can't interact with the user's desktop.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How can I do that?

Comment: Websearch. CreateDesktop.

Comment: Take a look at this useful article: [Desktop Switching](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7666/Desktop-Switching)

Answer (score -1):

I believe hooking `SetForegroundWindow` is better. Creating another desktop may lead to a much more sophisticated situation.